# Perl program using wrong arguments

Tags: linux, perl, command-line-interface

I am trying to create simple startup script in perl that will launch various programs on system startup. It is as follows

```
my @startupPrograms = qw(google-chrome thunderbird skype pidgin );
my @pagesToBeOpenedInChrome = qw(http://www.google.com/ http://stackoverflow.com/ https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox);

sub runPrograms() {
    print("Starting startup Programs... \n");
    foreach (@startupPrograms) {
        my $command = $_;
        print "Starting Program " . $command . "\n";
        if($command == "google-chrome") {
            foreach (@pagesToBeOpenedInChrome) {
                $command = $command . " " . $_;
            } 
        }
        `$command &`;
        print "Program " . $command . " started \n";
    }


}
```

But the output I am getting is

```
[aniket@localhost TestCodes]$ ./startUp.pl 
***** Welcome to startup program! *****
Starting startup Programs... 
Starting Program google-chrome
Program google-chrome http://www.google.com/ http://stackoverflow.com/ https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox started 
Starting Program thunderbird
Program thunderbird http://www.google.com/ http://stackoverflow.com/ https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox started 
Starting Program skype
Program skype http://www.google.com/ http://stackoverflow.com/ https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox started 
Starting Program pidgin
Program pidgin http://www.google.com/ http://stackoverflow.com/ https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox started
```

Why is taking the pagesToBeOpenedInChrome array contents in each command to be executed? Also it looks like if i put pidgin before other programs it takes forever to start pidgin(other programs are locked). Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: No need to break up your strings to interpolate variables: `"Program $command started\n"`. Also `for (...) { my $command = $_ ` is better written `for my $command (...)` (`for` and `foreach` are aliases).

Comment: Always add [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html "perldoc strict") and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html "perldoc warnings") to the beginning of your Perl code, until you know **exactly** why it is recommended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change

```
if($command == "google-chrome") {
```

to

```
if($command eq "google-chrome") {
```

in perl, you use eq or ne for text comparisons and == for numeric comparisons!

use the == for text basically says if $command is not empty or 0

Comment: Why does it evaluate $command == "google-chrome" to be true for all commands?

Comment: Because you are telling Perl to look at the variables as a number.

Comment: In perl, any number which is greater than 0 is true, so you are saying if ( (true) == (true) ) { }

Comment: here's some reading for ya - http://perlmeme.org/howtos/syntax/comparing_values.html

Comment: @AniketThakur Because the operator `==` converts both its arguments to numbers before doing its comparison. Any string that does not begin with a number, or can otherwise be converted to a number will be converted to zero `0`. And of course, `0 == 0` is true.